# O que está errado em: "Vão lá, curtem, compartilham! "

Tags: verbos, sintaxe, tempo-verbal, concordância-verbal

Eu li isto em um post no perfil do Instagram de uma amiga, por isso disse-lhe que achava que o correto seria: VÃO LÁ, CURTAM, COMPARTILHEM! Além da questão da concordância e do modo Imperativo, como explicar o porquê da diferença entre elas? Tem a ver também com as desinências dos verbos curtir/compartilhar? Um termina com "ir" e o outro termina com "ar"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Vão lá, curtem, compartilham!" não está incorreto, embora não me pareça ser a melhor escolha.

Se trata, provavelmente, do *imperativo polido* ou *cortês*, em que o significado é imperativo, mas a conjugação é feita no presente do indicativo.

Bastante frequente em pt-BR, esta forma é correta em pt-PT também, como colocado no Ciberdúvidas [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-imperativo-de-fazer-conjugado-pronominalmente/36199) e também [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-do-presente-do-indicativo-em-pedidos/22464):

> No contexto da formulação de uma ordem ou de um pedido, não é incorrecto usar o presente do indicativo (dividem) na primeira frase, como alternativa à segunda, com o verbo no presente do {#conjuntivo|subjuntivo} (dividam). Leia-se a Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo, de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (págs. 449/450):
>
> «É uma forma delicada de linguagem, e denota intimidade entre pessoas, um pedido feito no presente do indicativo quando, logicamente, deveria sê-lo no imperativo ou no futuro. Exemplo:
>
> "Você resolve-me isto amanhã" (= "Resolva-me isto amanhã"; ou: "Você me resolverá isto amanhã").»

E é também mencionado [neste site](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/emprego-tempo-presente-indicativo.html) e [neste artigo (pdf)](https://www.ufjf.br/praticasdelinguagem/files/2014/01/271-%e2%80%93-280-A-interface-do-portugu%c3%aas-e-do-italiano-nas-formula%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-ordens.pdf).

O imperativo formal seria, naturalmente, "curtam, compartilhem" (conferir [aqui](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/curtir) e [aqui](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/compartilhar)), e nessa frase me soa melhor que a forma com o presente do indicativo.

Comment: Não entendo como a tua resposta responde à pergunta: «O que está errado em: “Vão lá, curtem, compartilham! ” [?]» Podes adicionar algo que responda mais explicitamente? Em concreto, eu não entendo se a tua resposta defende que a forma "que também é correta em pt-PT" é "curtem, partilham", ou "curtam, partilham", ou ambas, ou...

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Entende agora?

Comment: Sim, está claríssimo, obrigado! :) Mas não acho que seja uma construção natural para o caso geral de pt-PT. Tecnicamente correto, mas na prática improvável. Vou ver se mais logo arranjo um tempo para escrever uma resposta mais centrada no português europeu. :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Nessa frase também em pt-BR não me soa natural.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigada pela resposta e pelas indicações de leitura! Preciso aprofundar mais nos verbos!

Comment: @VanusaEugenio Feliz em ajudar. Lembre-se de que você pode marcar respostas úteis com um "voto positivo" (_up vote_) e que mais te satisfizer, clicando em "aceitar". :)

Comment: Veja se fiz certo para lhe dar o "voto positivo", entrei há poucos dias e ainda não sei direito como funciona, ainda mais que está em inglês. Obrigada!

Comment: @VanusaEugenio Não sei se o voto que a postagem tem é teu ou não. Para votar positivamente, é só clicar na seta apontando para cima, à esquerda da postagem. E para aceitar a resposta, clique no sinal de certo (✓), também à esquerda, no topo. Confira essa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx4sU.png .

Comment: @stafusa, sim, o voto era o meu, só não tinha aceitado a resposta, o que acabei de fazer. Obrigada!